# wxWidgets create non resizeable frame

Tags: c++, gtk, wxwidgets

My from wxFrame derived class has a maximize button even after using the following window style:

```
wxDEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE &~(wxRESIZE_BORDER | wxMAXIMIZE_BOX)
```

The window is still resizeable through the window border, the maximize box and the window menu. Is it possible that the version of gtk2 has a bug?

Comment: wxDEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE contains wxRESIZE_BORDER.

Comment: &~ removes exactly those flags

Comment: what is your GTK+ version and OS/version? Are you under Ubuntu/Unity?

Comment: Kubuntu 16.04, but happened on Xubuntu 16.04, too. gtk is 2.24.30.

Comment: from http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1/classwx_window.html - try wxBORDER_NONE.or wxNO_BORDER if you have old wx version.

Comment: This removes the window border and titlebar all together.

Comment: but you will not be able to resize, right? Also, can ou modify the minimal sample and make sure that it does not work? If it doesn't - please file a bug at trac.wxwidgets.org. It requires registration and approval, so don't be scared if you don't see it initially. Or you can try to inquire on forums.wxwidgets.org

Comment: It's still resizeable through the taskbar. For some reason wxDialog is not resizeable. I will dig a bit into the source code to see what causes that. I will try VZ's answer first and then maybe fill a bug report. Thanks for you patience!

Answer (score 1):

When using X11 GTK+ backend, wxWidgets basically just calls `gdk_window_set_decorations()` and `gdk_window_set_functions()` functions which are supposed to communicate the correct hints to the window manager, so it looks like they just don't work with the KDE window manager, unfortunately.

If you'd like to confirm this, I'd recommend taking GTK+ "Hello world" program and adding calls to these functions to it. If it does work there, but doesn't work in wxGTK, it would be a bug in the latter and you should report it. But if it doesn't work there neither, I'm afraid there is not much that can be done about it.